# JS, Randomly select every item from a 2d array

Tags: javascript, sorting, random

Array is 40 by 40 so [0 - 39][0 - 39].

is there a way that I can go through the array and select every item without selecting an item twice but do it randomly, 
so no a loop like *for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++)*.
sorry if my explanation is bad

Converted the array into a 1d Array

```
newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < gridsize; i ++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < gridsize; j ++) {
    newArray.push(grid[i][j])
  }
}
newArray = shuffle(newArray)
```

then I'm going through the array like so

```
for (var x = 0; x < newArray.length; x ++) {
  i = newArray[x].x
  j = newArray[x].y
    switch(grid[i][j].id) {
```

so that Because the array has been shuffled I can get a new random spot to search, is there a more efficient way than this?

Comment: Oh there are multiple ways, could you share with us what have you tried so we could help debug your code? As I'm sure you don't expect us to write the code for you :-)

Comment: Standard approach would be to make arrays for each dimension containing the numbers 0 through 39, and then [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Have a 1D array that represents all 1600 elements. Shuffle the array [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/12646864). Use that array to lookup the elements.